# Why isnt the old background being overwriten?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, imagefilter

I have a canvas background image that I'm filtering to to gray scale. When I save the canvas as JSON I want the background's image filter removed. How come when I overwrite the canvas background with its setter method the filtered background remains in the JSON?

Applying filtering to background

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(image_library_selected_url, (function(image){
    image.filters[0] = grayscale;
    image.applyFilters((function(){
        this.canvas.backgroundImage = image.getElement();
        canvas.backgroundImage.name = image_library_selected_url;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    }).bind(this));
}).bind(this));
```

Removing filtering and converting the canvas to JSON

```
//canvas.backgroundImage.name holds the src of the original image
var bg_img = canvas.backgroundImage.name;
canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg_img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    if (obj.type === 'named-image') {
        obj.filters=[];
        obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    }
});

canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
var data = JSON.stringify(canvas);
```

At this point the data goes off to the database and a nonfiltered background image remains on the screen...

When I refresh the page the saved data is reloaded into the page except the filter (of only the background) remains. If I clear the background entirely with:

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
```

The background data is erased as expected and is never saved.

If i do:

```
//canvas.backgroundImage.name holds the src of the original image
var bg_img = canvas.backgroundImage.name;
canvas.setBackgroundImage('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg_img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Visually the background appears to be correct but no background data is saved

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the unfiltered background wasnt loading fast enough and the call back wasn't made in time.

```
//canvas.backgroundImage.name holds the src of the original image
var bg_img = canvas.backgroundImage.name;
canvas.setBackgroundImage(bg_img, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();

    ...other processing

    var data = JSON.stringify(canvas);

    ...process json data
});
```